# Which hash functions provide 128 bit resistance?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, sha-256, md5, preimage-resistance

I was wondering out of the functions (MD5, SHA-1, SHA-256, and SHA-512), do all provide 128-bit pre-image resistance and 128-bit second-image resistance?

Also, out of these hash functions, do only SHA-256 and SHA-512 provide 128-bit collision resistance? (Due to $l/2$ bits of security)

Answer (score 4):

Let first a table on the bit security.

| Hash | Rel. Year | Pre-images | Second Pre-images | Collision Resistance | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MD5 | 1992 | 128-bit | 128-bit | [immediately broken](https://github.com/corkami/collisions) | **compromised** |
| SHA-1 | 1995 | 160-bit | 160-bit | [broken](https://shattered.io/) | **compromised** |
| SHA-256 | 2001 | 256-bit | 256-bit | 128-bit | secure |
| SHA-512 | 2001 | 512-bit | 512-bit | 256-bit | secure |

While there is [an attack](https://doi.org/10.1007%2F978-3-642-01001-9_8) on the pre-image of MD5 slightly less than the 128-bit that is given as $~2^{123.4}$, the actual cost is larger than the generic pre-image attack, so the pre-image is still non-broken. The collision resistance, on the other hand, [is ultra fast](https://github.com/corkami/collisions), less than 5 minutes.

Remember that the multi-target attack on the pre-images makes any 128-bit output insecure.

SHA-1's collision resistance has been [shuttered](https://shattered.io/) in practice and should not be used in practice anymore. Use at least 256-bit output hash functions like SHA-256, SHA3-256, Blake2b, or Shake series. This will help you secure from both classical and quantum attacks.

- 23 February 2017, the [Google team shuttered](https://shattered.io/static/shattered.pdf) SHA-1 with $2^{63.1}$ SHA-1 evaluations and managed to produce two PDFs has the same SHA-1 hashes. This is an identical-prefix collision attack.
- 24 April 2019, chosen-prefix collisions in approximately $~2^{68}$ SHA-1 evaluations by [Leurent and Peyrin](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-02424900/file/SHA1_EC19.pdf)

The attack on SHA2-x is currently only possible on reduced rounds in which the researchers exhibit the power of their attack by reducing the rounds of the compression function.

For example; [Bicliques for Preimages: Attacks on Skein-512 and the SHA-2 family](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/286.pdf) works on 45 out of 64 with the complexity $2^{255.5}$ for pre-image attack on SHA-256. This means that if SHA-256 was designed as 45 rounds instead of 64, its pre-image resistance was broken with this attack. Fortunately, the standard doesn't reduce the rounds of SHAx series we always use them as full rounds.

Comment: @CryptoGuru: "The attack on SHA2-x is currently on possible in reduced rounds." means 'attacks on deliberately weakened variants of SHA2-x that we don't actually use in practice'.  kelalaka knows this; however being more explicit in explaining what this means might not be a bad idea...

Comment: What's the source for 150-bit SHA-1 Second Pre-images?

Comment: @fgrieu nothing than my pure typo :)